# mobile version FASTER than AMP. AMP showing less

Tags: performance, amp-html

We end an optimization project for our mobile version and we did know the performance was very good (AMP level good). We also noticed AMP started to show less and less. We run some tests and on multiple articles and we found this:

[12 ms] Canonical page response time
**[16 ms] AMP page response time [INFO: AMP page fetch is slower than Canonical page]**
**[20 ms] Google AMP Cache response time [INFO: AMP Cache page fetch is slower than Canonical page]** 
[0.75 X] Canonical / AMP response time factor
[0.6 X] Canonical / Google AMP Cache response time factor

This rises the following questions for us:

1) will AMP still show if the canonical version is faster?
2) if AMP is not showing, we are out of the AMP carrousel, which will damage our organic search traffic. How can we avoid that?

Regards
Hernán.

Answer (score 0):

The AMP version will show as long as you have bi-directional rel-amphtml and rel-canonical links between your pages.